# Disable support for SSLv3 for iOS 9 and above

Tags: ios

We recently ran into an issue when one of the website that we accessed within our application using WebView disabled support for SSLv3. The WebView started giving SSL handshake error. Per articles on Apple developer forum, Apple by default no longer supports SSLv3 from version 11 (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6767).

Can anyone advise how I can disable SSLv3 for my app that targets iOS 9 and above operating system? Not sure if NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion is an appropriate fix here.

Thanks

Comment: WebView (macOS), UIWebView (iOS) or WKWebView (iOS/macOS) ?

Comment: @nathan I am looking for solution with UIWebView, but thoughts on others are welcome. Thanks.